# Is there a visual indication for tester when testing in-app v2? (not sure if I can continue with purchase)

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing

I remember when I am tester in in-app v3 and when I want to purchase any item, there will be a text message saying that I am a tester and that I will not be charged for the purchase.

Now, I am testing an app with in-app billing v2. When I download the test build from the Play Store and for example try to rate it, I will get a message that I am a tester and that I cannot rate the app.

However, **when I open the purchase pop-up in the app I see not indication that I am a tester or that I will not be charged**. I went thru all the steps and came to entering my password, and have not seen a single clue that I will not be charged for the purchase.

What is your advise? And what it the practice in v2 - do I get charged and immediately refunded or I don't get charged at all (since v2 does not have information text as v3)?

Note 1: I have set test account on the Play Developer console. The proof for this is a message I get when I try to rate the app I am testing.

Note 2: I also uploaded the build to Beta with a `Toast` of `versionCode` so I am positive that I am testing the proper build as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was just testing v2 and I don't recall seeing anything regarding a 'Test Purchase' while stepping through the purchase process. I was testing an Alpha build in the console. You should notice the 'test purchase' on the receipt emails though(stating that you won't be charged)? You should also see this via Google Wallet as well. Provided you have access to the emails and/or Google Wallet...

Comment: I was actually charged but was able to refund charges. And I am set as a test user in the Play Console. Very weird...

Comment: were you logged into a different gmail account on the device?

Comment: No, I was logged using the same Google account which is in the tester part of the Play Developer